# why cant i make a button to make child window electron

Tags: electron

how do I make a button that will open an new window

so I've made like

```
<button onclick="openwin()" style = "position: absolute;; top:225px; left:310px;"  class="Button" 
>new win</button>
```

what should I put in the `openwin` function that I've made

```
function openwin(){
    const electron = require('electron')
    const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
    const win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })
    win.show()
}
```

but the window doesn't show
instead there's an error coming

[image: This is What Coming out]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying to run this code in your renderer process. As per the [docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#browserwindow), the `BrowserWindow` is only accessible in the main process.

You need your renderer script to send a message down to your main process and have *it* create the `BrowserWindow`.

You'd enable node in your main window if you haven't already:

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: true }});
mainWindow.loadFile("myPage.html");
```

And your`openwin` function would do:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron");
ipcRenderer.send("openWindow");
```

And your main script would listen to that message:

```
const { ipcMain, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
ipcMain.on("openWindow", () => {
    const win = new BrowserWindow();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to load resource on your new window like `loadURL()` or `loadFile()`

I like enough issue of visibility window. You need to set relation of your windows (main and others) like this :

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

const top = new BrowserWindow()
const child = new BrowserWindow({ parent: top })
child.show()
top.show()
```

or you also can set this new window like a modal :

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

const child = new BrowserWindow({ parent: top, modal: true, show: false })
child.loadURL('https://www.example.com')
child.once('ready-to-show', () => {
  child.show()
})
```

Comment: browserwindow is not a constructor

Comment: @FarrelAthaillah as pushkin told you you hava to instantiate your BrowserWindow in your main process (eg main.js or index.js as you named it)